# json data into proper require array format in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

In php I am getting json data and after `echo "<pre>";` and print_r like this -(this is small data I am getting very big data)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [date] => 2015-05-30
            [total] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [date] => 2015-05-31
            [total] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4863
            [date] => 2015-05-30
            [total] => 183
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4863
            [date] => 2015-05-31
            [total] => 140
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5126
            [date] => 2015-05-30
            [total] => 131292
        )
)
```

Requirement -
I want to display thid data in this table format ->

```
id  2015-05-30  2015-05-31  difference <br/> 
0       8           4           -4     <br/> 
4863    183        140          -43    <br/> 
5126    131292                         <br/>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this data looks like it is saved in a database, I expect you can make sure, that the data is always from two dates, ordered by those (as in your example array).

If this is the case, I would probably do it like this:

```
$array = array(array('id' => 0, 'date' => '2015-05-30', 'total' => 8),
               array('id' => 0, 'date' => '2015-05-31', 'total' => 4),
               array('id' => 4863, 'date' => '2015-05-30', 'total' => 183),
               array('id' => 4863, 'date' => '2015-05-31', 'total' => 140),
               array('id' => 5126, 'date' => '2015-05-30', 'total' => 131292));

$newArray = array();
$dates = array();


foreach($array as $entry) {
  if(!isset($newArray[$entry['id']])) $newArray[$entry['id']] = array();
  if(!in_array($entry['date'], $dates)) array_push($dates, $entry['date']);
  array_push($newArray[$entry['id']], array($entry['total'], $entry['date']));
}

echo "id&nbsp;" . $dates[0] . "&nbsp;" . $dates[1] . "&nbsp;" . "difference&nbsp;<br/>";
foreach($newArray as $id => $entry) {
  echo $id . "&nbsp;" . (($entry[0][1]==$dates[0]) ? $entry[0][0] . "&nbsp;" . $entry[1][0] : "&nbsp;" . $entry[0][0]) .  "&nbsp;" . ((count($entry) == 2) ? $entry[1][0]-$entry[0][0] : "") ."&nbsp;<br>";
}
```

Comment: I am getting data in json response and I cant edit queries because its coming from other source

Comment: and I am storing data in this format - $json_Arr[$json_value['id']][$json_value['date']] = $json_value['total'];

Comment: Hi marc,  In this i am getting one problem...if I have value of 31 and of 30th is empty value so what should I do.... Right now 31st value is coming in 30th's column

Comment: It should be in the correct column (there should be 2 spaces after the id - aren't there?)

Comment: no no... suppose we have one more data like this-    
[5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 86222
            [date] => 2015-05-31
            [total] => 18046
        )
---in this I am getting 31st date data in 30th column
spacing is correct

Comment: can you please help in that 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798178/json-data-into-proper-require-multiple-array-format-in-php