# json data into proper require multiple array format in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have json response like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 65070
            [date] => 2015-06-05
            [hour] => 0
            [total] => 18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 65070
            [date] => 2015-06-05
            [hour] => 2
            [total] => 32
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 65070
            [date] => 2015-06-07
            [hour] => 0
            [total] => 27
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 65070
            [date] => 2015-06-07
            [hour] => 2
            [total] => 35
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1838680
            [date] => 2015-06-05
            [hour] => 0
            [total] => 957
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1838680
            [date] => 2015-06-05
            [hour] => 2
            [total] => 1266
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1838680
            [date] => 2015-06-07
            [hour] => 0
            [total] => 409
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1838680
            [date] => 2015-06-07
            [hour] => 2
            [total] => 1528
        )
)
```

I want output like this

```
id  Hour    2015-06-05  2015-06-07  Difference
65070   0   18  27  9
65070   2   32  35  3
1838680 0   957 409 -548
1838680 2   1266
```

Hour is not fixed to 0 or 2. It can be more than 2 or 1 also

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you already try anything? Show us your code.

Comment: $newArray = array();
$dates = array();
foreach($array as $entry) {
  if(!isset($newArray[$entry['id']])) $newArray[$entry['id']] = array();
  if(!in_array($entry['date'], $dates)) array_push($dates, $entry['date']);
  array_push($newArray[$entry['id']], array($entry['total'], $entry['date']));
}
echo "id" . $dates[0] . "" . $dates[1] . "" . "difference";
foreach($newArray as $id => $entry) {
  echo $id . "&nbsp;" . (($entry[0][1]==$dates[0]) ? $entry[0][0] . "&nbsp;" . $entry[1][0] : "&nbsp;" . $entry[0][0]) .  "&nbsp;" . ((count($entry) == 2) ? $entry[1][0]-$entry[0][0] : "") ."&nbsp;<br>";
}

Comment: this was the code when hour was not there.. but now I want hour wise also

Comment: Please [edit] the code into the question, as comments do not preserve formatting, and explain exactly what is giving you trouble, as this sounds like a fairly easy change.

Comment: trying to store in format -<br>
$newArray[$entry['id']][$entry['hour']] [$entry['date']] = $entry['total']; <br>
not getting how to format properly

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what to write, it is routine code

```
$newArray = array(); 
$dates = array(); 

foreach($array as $entry) {
   $newArray[$entry['id']][$entry['hour']][$entry['date']]= $entry['total'];
   if(!in_array($entry['date'], $dates)) $dates[] = $entry['date'];
   }
sort($dates);

echo "id hour ". $dates[0] . " " . $dates[1] . " " . "difference"."\n";

foreach($newArray as $id => $hours)
  foreach($hours as $hour => $entry)
     echo  $id ." " . $hour  . " " 
           . $entry[$dates[0]] . " " 
           . $entry[$dates[1]] . " "
           . ($entry[$dates[1]] - $entry[$dates[0]]) . "\n";
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/380407)

Comment: acually  $entry[$dates[0]] . " " 
           . $entry[$dates[1]] . " " are undefined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679915/json-data-into-proper-require-array-format-in-php
in this I am getting proper data but new requirement is to add hour wise also

Comment: And what data it echos ?